# No type-erasure for JpaRepository's generics?

Tags: java, spring-data, type-erasure

I use the data-repository like this:

```
interface HerbadgeRepository extends JpaRepository<Herbadge, Integer> {
}
```

At oracle [they say](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> To implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure ...

I am confused, the bytecode must be like this:

```
interface HerbadgeRepository extends JpaRepository<?, ?> {
}
```

So how do spring-data knows what entity must be returned?

Answer (score -1):

Spring data analyze class signature with Reflection. You could obtian class types with code:

```
HerbadgeRepository.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0].getTypeName()
```

Comment: Generics != Parameters

Comment: sorry, didn`t understand idea of your comment. I have provided way to obtain type